# Wordpress loading wrong language for Facebook SDK

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We are trying to embed Facebook posts into Wordpress using the URL of the post.  This works fine except for the language is wrong.  Instead of the language appearing in English, it is appearing in Arabic.

I believe I have traced the problem to the Facebook SDK that is loaded by Wordpress.

This is the code that Facebook says to add to the page

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&amp;version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

This is what Wordpress is loading

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<p><script>(function(d, s, id) {  
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s) [0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ar_AR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I believe that the issue is the "ar_AR" in the Facebook connection url instead of "en_US".  However, I cannot figure out how or where that is controlled.

I checked the language selection in Wordpress and English is selected.  I tried a fresh Wordpress 4.7 installation with no plugins and the problem still persists.

Here is an example post that comes up in Arabic on the website.  This is also what we are inserting into Wordpress to create the embedded post.

https://www.facebook.com/farahdhukai/videos/1217650958285047/

Here is where it is appearing in Arabic instead of English

http://mvs.dev.clickharder.net/facebook-sdk-test/

The top embed is using the Wordpress embed feature by just adding the URL of the video.  The bottom embed is using the Facebook iframe embed method for testing purposes.

I haven't figured out how to either disable the Facebook SDK within Wordpress so I can insert it myself or how to change it from ar_AR to en_US.

I have searched through every reference to "Facebook" in a fresh Wordpress install and have come up empty handed.  I can't find a references for "ar_AR" within Wordpress that relates to this issue.

We are trying to avoid using the iframe method of embedding posts.  It is not ideal for our situation so that is not a solution for us.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: identify which plugin inserts the js sdk and change it in that plugin

Comment: _“This is also what we are inserting into Wordpress to create the embedded post”_ – what, just the URL – no shortcode, nothing else? // This is probably using the OEmbed API, and with that the code to embed the SDK is part of the API result. Presumably it tries to load the SDK in the language of the actual post, if not instructed otherwise. Go and check what settings are available regarding OEmbed in your WP dashboard.

Comment: @luschn There is no plugin that inserts the js sdk installed on the website.  This is occurring with a clean install of Wordpress 4.7 and no plugins installed.

Comment: @CBroe  We are copying the URL directly into the Wordpress editor.  There is no shortcode.  I tried using the [embed] shortcode and the problem persists.  I agree that is is probably a part of the API result.  It is not due to the language of the actual post.  I thought that could be the case too but  it happens on other embedded posts including a Ford truck embedded post that was written by a company in Arkansas.  There are no OEmbed options in the WP dashboard that I know if.

Comment: I tried embedding the post using the [embed] shortcode and followed the instructions on this page with no luck.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds

Here is the code that Wordpress uses for the Embed API

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/embed.php#L0

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video/oembed.json/?url=https://www.facebook.com/farahdhukai/videos/1217650958285047/ returns code that uses the en_US SDK address though; so the problem might still be with what exactly WordPress does here. For a quick fix, I’d probably go and write a little content filter that looks for the “wrong” SDK address, and replaces it with the right one.

Comment: @CBroe That is the solution I went with.  I just wrote a quick filter that uses str_replace() and looks for the /ar_AR/ and replaces it with /en_US/.  Still don't know why it does it... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CBroe provided the same solution I went with.  I added the following code to replace the reference.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'facebook_sdk_replace' );
function facebook_sdk_replace( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $content = str_replace("/ar_AR/", "/en_US/", $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for wrong language is location of your web server.

Facebook obviously detects language based on your server's IP address.

This is the workaround, which avoids performance overhead:

```
function oembed_result($content, $url, $args) {
    return str_replace("https://connect.facebook.net/ar_AR/", "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/", $content);
}
add_filter('oembed_result','oembed_result', 10, 3);
```

Don't forget to delete cache from the database after that:

```
DELETE FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE "_oembed%"
```