# Change wordpress default Facebook embedding language

Tags: wordpress, facebook, function, facebook-graph-api

Since WP 4 (I believe) Wordpress support embedding Facebook posts by default.
The problem I am facing is that because of [this](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/40656) FB related problem, all my posts are embedded in random languages, based on the Cloudflare's IP location

What I'd like to do is somehow manually replace

`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js....";`

with something custom, like 
`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/";`

I tried a solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41550989/wordpress-loading-wrong-language-for-facebook-sdk), in January, but didn't work. Namely:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'facebook_sdk_replace' );
function facebook_sdk_replace( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() ) {
        $content = str_replace("/nl_NL/", "/en_US/", $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Suggestions?

EDIT: I do not add the Facebook embedding at all. This is all default Wordpress behavior. All I do is to copy the URL of a Facebook post into the text block on WP. [Like here.](https://en.support.wordpress.com/facebook-integration/facebook-embeds/)

Comment: Where have you put your FB script (header?, footer?) and on what pages are you embedding the posts (home?, blog?, single page?)

Comment: Isn't this feature comes with a plugin?

Comment: @dferenc No, there's no plugin involved. This is the default behavior.

Comment: @Und3rTow shouldn't matter on which page, but the current example is for posts. Also, I don't put the script anywhere. Facebook does this by itself. All I do is to insert FB post URL to the "text" block